# Locator Problem in IOS 13.3 in appium inspector?

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-ios, iosdeployment

I can't able to find the drop down elements in App source of Appium inspector.Before IOS 13 version options was showing but in IOS 13.3 elements are missing. My dev hasn't any idea about this issues. could suggest what dev should do?
Appium -1.15.1
IOS - 13.3
Xcode - 11.3.1

Comment: Any success with this?